# React Native - Problem with state updates with an array within an object within an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, typeorm

since I am quite new to react native, I ran into an issue with updating my state. I got an array of shopping carts in the state, these hold information to the cart and all the items the user selected to sync to the server. Whenever I try to sync the carts with my function to the server I get the error, that the items are not defined in the state object anymore. Does someone have a clue how to fix this?

I am using TypeORM locally for saving the changes for the user, which is actually working, but the state update is not working, the items array in the cart after the `setCarts(newCarts)` call is always undefined. Since the items hold the synchronized timestamp, I am iterating in `getSyncState()` over them to get the sync state of the cart itself in a FlatList.

```
const syncAllCarts = async () => {
    let tempCarts = carts;
    let newCarts = tempCarts.map(async cart => {
      if (getSyncState(cart) === 0) {
        cart.items = cart.items.map(async item => {
          if (item.state !== 1) {
            postData({
              SiteNumber: item.site.sitenum,
              SiteTitle: item.site.title,
              ArticleNumber: item.article.artnum,
              Quantity: item.quantity,
              Uuid: cart.uuid,
              Scanned: cart.created
            }).then(async (data) => {
              const itemRepo = getRepository(Item);
              const dbItem = await itemRepo.findOne({where: {id: item.id}});
              if (data.status === true) {
                const syncDate = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);
                dbItem.state = 1;
                dbItem.synchronized = syncDate;
                item.state = 1;
                item.synchronized = syncDate;
                await itemRepo.save(dbItem);
              } else {
                Alert.alert('Fehler bei der Übertragung', 'Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, prüfen Sie Ihre Verbindung.');
                dbItem.state = -1;
                item.state = -1;
                dbItem.message = typeof response !== 'undefined' ? response.message : 'no connection';
                await itemRepo.save(dbItem);
              }
            }).catch((e) => {
              Alert.alert('Fehler bei der Verbindung', 'Leider ist ein Fehler aufgetreten, prüfen Sie Ihre Verbindung.');
              console.log(e);
            });
          }
          return item;
        })
      }
      return cart;
    });
    setCarts(newCarts);
  }

  const postData = async (data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(host + 'post/json', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Token: token,
        cache: 'no-cache',
        redirect: 'follow',
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer',
        connection: 'keep-alive'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await response.json();
  }
```

```
const getSyncState = (cart) => {
    let syncState = 1;
    cart.items.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.state !== 1) {
        syncState = 0;
      }
    })
    return syncState;
  }
```

Comment: You are doing async operations inside an synchronous function (Array.map).

Comment: @ShanakaRusith Okay, fixed that, but does not work either way...The state gets updated and the items are undefined after the update, which leads to the error ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (Evaluating 'cart.items.forEach')``` in the getSyncState() function